# Appcelerator studio won't start (on loading screen)

Tags: loading, appcelerator-studio

After updating Appcelerator Studio it won't load. Starting it produces starting screen showing "loading studio" 4ever. It is just stuck there. Any idea on what might have caused this?

Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMMYj.png)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too (on a Mac). You can try this:

- download and install the latest Appcelerator version
- logout of Appcelerator using CLI or terminal window (if you can open it of course), using "appc logout -D".

Start Appcelerator again and login again. This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

‘jstack’ is an effective command line tool to capture thread dumps. jstack tool is shipped in JDK_HOMEbin folder. Here is the command that you need to issue to capture thread dump:

```
jstack -l <pid> <file-path>
```

where
pid: is the Process Id of the application, whose thread dump should be captured

file-path: is the file path where thread dump will be written in to.
go for-:

Example:

```
jstack -l 37320 > /opt/tmp/threadDump.txt
```

Library/java/javaVertualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/content/home/bin/jvisualvm

refer to this link for better understand
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-take-thread-dumps-7-options

Launch the jvisualvm. On the left panel, you will notice all the java applications that are running on your machine. You need to select your application from the list (see the red color highlight in the below diagram). This tool also has the capability to capture thread dumps from the java processes that are running in remote host as well.

Now go to the “Threads” tab. Click on the “Thread Dump” button as shown in the below image. Now Thread dumps would be generated.

Java Mission Control (JMC) is a tool that collects and analyze data from Java applications running locally or deployed in production environments. This tool has been packaged into JDK since Oracle JDK 7 Update 40. This tool also provides an option to take thread dumps from the JVM. JMC tool is present in Library/java/javaVertualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/content/home/bin/jmc.exe

Once you launch the tool, you will see all the Java processes that are running on your local host. Note: JMC also has the ability to connect with java processes running on a remote host. Now on the left panel click on the “Flight Recorder” option that is listed below the Java process for which you want to take thread dumps.

Here in the “Thread Dump” field, you can select the interval in which you want to capture thread dump. As per the above example, every 60 seconds thread dump will be captured. After the selection is complete start the Flight recorder.

Finally appc logout 
and Login.